# How to switch after clicking on the button in the menu to a fragment in which data binding is used

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Getting error hint with `CoursesFragment.newInstance()` line:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.bottom_nav_bar_main , menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val intent : Intent
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.itemCourses -> {
                val fragment = CoursesFragment.newInstance()
            }
        }
        return true
    }


}

class CoursesFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = FragmentCoursesBinding.inflate(inflater , container , false)
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

How it looks in **Android Studio**:

[MainActivity code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9EBZ.png)

[CourcesFragment code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrD12.png)

Comment: val fragment = CoursesFragment.newInstance()
newInstance() doesn't work

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Add `FragmentContainerView` to your activity xml

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Step 2 : In your `MainActivity.class` file, declare `FragmentManager`

```
private FragmentManager manager;
```

Step 3 :  Initialize `FragmentManager` in `onCreate()`

```
manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Step 4 : In your `onOptionsItemSelected` begin this fragment

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
manager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, YourFragment.class, bundle, "TAG")
    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
    //.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_enter, R.anim.anim_exit)
    .addToBackStack("TAG")
    .commit();
```